# Three.JS - How to load textures of material from data URL?

Tags: javascript, json, three.js, textures

I'm using three.js and I have put together a mesh (.obj), a material (.mtl) and a couple of textures into a single JSON object.

The mesh and material come from Blender's wavefront obj export.

The JSON (truncated):

```
{
    "data": {
        "type": "b64obj",
        "material": "--Long base64-encoded Material data--",
        "mesh": "--Long base64-encoded Mesh data--",
        "textures": {
            "texture.jpg": "base64-encoded image",
            "anothertexture.jpg": "base64-encoded image",
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the routine that loads it (without the base64-decoding part):

```
var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
var materials = mtlLoader.parse(data.material);
materials.preload();

var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
var object = objLoader.parse(data.mesh);
renderObj(object); //start using it inside the application once it is there
```

The .mtl refers to image files and the MTLLoader would expect them on hard drive. How do I tell to use the object with the textures inside instead?

Answer (score 3):

Brace yourself, this is going to get hacky. You need to monkeypatch MTLLoader and intercept requests for those URLs, replacing them with your Data URIs.

```
var json = JSON.parse(myJSON);

var _loadTexture = THREE.MTLLoader.MaterialCreator.prototype.loadTexture;

THREE.MTLLoader.MaterialCreator.prototype.loadTexture = function ( url, mapping, onLoad, onProgress, onError ) {

  url = json.data.textures[ url ] || url;
  return _loadTexture( url, mapping, onLoad, onProgress, onError );

};
```

I've [proposed a less hacky way of doing this](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/11259) — I use it to support drag-and-drop — but am not sure whether it's common enough to be officially supported.

Comment: Hmmm... that is the compromise solution I already did.... I hoped, there is a better way but it doesn't seems to be there.... :-(......  Thank you :-)